# How to access the hidden values in JSP using plan HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have some hidden values as shown below.

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_clientCount" value="ClientCount" />
<input type="hidden" id="id_AppCount" value="AppCount" />
```

Now i would like to access them in my JSP page like this.

```
<div style="margin-left: 30%; color: green;"><b>Confirmation</b></div><br/>
        client value:  <script>document.getElementById('id_clientCount').value</script>
        app Value :  <script>document.getElementById('id_AppCount').value</script>
<div id="testChild" style="height: 15em"></div>
```

Correct me if i am doing wrong.

**Note :** This entire code in single JSP Page

**Expected Output is :**

> client value: ClientCount 
>  app Value : AppCount

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to print that value on screen, use  `document.write(...)` to print .Like below :

```html
<input type="hidden" id="id_clientCount" value="ClientCount" />
<input type="hidden" id="id_AppCount" value="AppCount" />
<div style="margin-left: 30%; color: green;"><b>Confirmation</b></div><br/> client value:
<script>
 document.write(document.getElementById('id_clientCount').value);
</script>
<br>app Value :
<script>
   document.write(document.getElementById('id_AppCount').value);
</script>
<div id="testChild" style="height: 15em"></div>
```

Comment: one more dooubt Swathi, if its pure JSP page its not working.

Comment: Can you suggest me

Comment: you don't value ? by using `document.write()..` ? what do you mean by pure jsp can you elaborate ?

Comment: in Pure HTML i will get the value. but in JSP Page I will not get the value. am i doing any mistake. or missed some thing.

Comment: if possible can you come to chat room

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<input type="hidden" id="id_clientCount" value="ClientCount" />
<input type="hidden" id="id_AppCount" value="AppCount" />


<div style="margin-left: 30%; color: green;"><b>Confirmation</b></div><br/>
        client value:  <span id="id_clientCountId"></span><BR>
        app Value :  <span id="id_AppCountId"></span>
<div id="testChild" style="height: 15em"></div>



<script>
fill();
function fill(){
document.getElementById("id_clientCountId").innerHTML  = document.getElementById('id_clientCount').value;
document.getElementById("id_AppCountId").innerHTML  = document.getElementById('id_AppCount').value;

}

</script>
```